# Re-assign value to variable if rand() repeats a number

Tags: c

I am making a tic tac toe game in which the user competes against the computer. Whenever the person chooses a spot between 1 and 9, the computer needs to choose one too. For this, I am using rand(). However, if the spot is already taken, I need the computer to calculate a new one. I've tried using while and do-while loops but when I apply them, cmd stops working and doesn't let me continue the game.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct symbol{
    int marcado;
    char simbolo;
} SPOT;

SPOT casilla1 = {0,'1'};
SPOT casilla2 = {0,'2'};
SPOT casilla3 = {0,'3'};

void table();
void User();
void AI();

int main(){
    system("cls");
    User();
    AI();
    Check();
    return 0;
}

void table(){
    printf("\n        %c   |   %c   |   %c ",spot1.symbol,spot2.symbol,spot3.symbol);
}
```

this is the function in which the user chooses a spot:

```
void User(){

    char choice; 

    do{

        do{
            board();
            printf("\n\nChoose a spot: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c",&choice);
        }while(choice < '1' || choice > '3');

        switch(choice){
            case '1': if(choice == '1'){

                        system("cls");

                        if(casilla1.marcado == 1){
                            printf("\noccupied\n");
                        }

                        else if(casilla1.marcado == 0){
                            casilla1.marcado = 1;
                            casilla1.simbolo = 'X';

                            AI();
                        }
                    }
            break;

            case '2': if(choice == '2'){

                        system("cls");

                        if(casilla2.marcado == 1){
                            printf("\noccupied\n");
                        }

                        else if(casilla2.marcado == 0){
                            casilla2.marcado = 1;
                            casilla2.simbolo = 'X';

                            AI();
                        }   
                    }   
            break;

            case '3': if(choice == '3'){

                        system("cls");

                        if(casilla3.marcado == 1){
                            printf("\noccupied");
                        }

                        else if(casilla3.marcado == 0){
                            casilla3.marcado = 1;
                            casilla3.simbolo = 'X';

                            AI();
                        }   
                    }   
            break;  

    }while(Check() != 0 && Check() != 1);
}
```

and this is the function for the computer. In which I am having trouble in the 'else if' statements since I don't know what to put in them.

```
void AI(){

    int random;

    srand(time(NULL));

    random = rand() % 3 + 1;

    if (random == 1){
        if(casilla1.marcado == 0){      
            casilla1.simbolo = 'O';
            casilla1.marcado = 1;
        }

        else if(casilla1.marcado == 1){
            random = rand() % 3 + 1
        }
    }

        if (random == 2){
            if(casilla2.marcado == 0){      
                casilla2.simbolo = 'O';
                casilla2.marcado = 1;
            }

            else if(casilla2.marcado == 1){
                random = rand() % 3 + 1;
            }
        }

        if (random == 3){
            if(casilla3.marcado == 0){      
                casilla3.simbolo = 'O';
                casilla3.marcado = 1;
            }

            else if(casilla3.marcado == 1){
                random = rand() % 3 + 1;
            }
        }   
}
```

As I said before, I've tried putting the whole AI() inside the different types of loops, putting only rand() inside them, and so on, and still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

First, choose your data structures better. Instead of:

```
SPOT casilla1 = {0,'1'};
SPOT casilla2 = {0,'2'};
SPOT casilla3 = {0,'3'};
```

use

```
SPOT casilla[3] = { {0,'1'}, {0,'2'}, {0,'3'} };
```

As a consequence, the `switch` constructs are not needed any longer. Instead of:

```
if(casilla1.marcado == 0){
if(casilla2.marcado == 0){
if(casilla3.marcado == 0){
```

use:

```
if(casilla[random-1].marcado == 0){
```

---

> the person chooses a spot between 1 and 9

and

```
random = rand() % 9 + 1;
```

You only have 3 `casilla`. Where are the other 6?

---

> I've tried using while and do-while loops

In `AI()` there are no loops. Maybe you can show us a code with loops?

---

```
printf("\n\nChoose a spot: ");
fflush(stdin);
```

You probably wanted to `fflush()` `stdout`?

Comment: It says 9 because I modified most of the code and took out 6 spots so it wouldn't be as long in here, a mistake. I will modify the rest in the morning since it's 2am and I can't keep thinking about code right now.

Comment: As you can see in my example, you have an array of `struct`s. I did not touch that part. Read again the answer, and you will find even how to access struct members of an array element ;)

Comment: Removing 6 elements will not make your program better in any way. Please put them back :)

Comment: sorry, I meant modified so it wouldn't be as long in here as the actual code! (since i'm pretty new at stackoverflow and coding in general). I saw that you kept the structs, i'm going to change that tomorrow as well to make the code shorter and easier to follow too, thanks!